# Comparing string fields not working

Tags: java

i have a several objects with a String field in each; i am trying to compare the strings but i cant get the code to work, it allways returns null, even when the strings are equal.

songsList is an Arraylist of this objects.

```
public Song findSong(Song song){
    for(int i=0; i<songsList.size(); i++){
        if(song.getName().equals(songsList.get(i).getName())){
            return songsList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You need to show what is there in `song` and  `songsList`

Comment: your songsList is static?

Comment: As I don't see whole code of yours, I assume 'songsList' is an ArrayList. Did you try songsList.contains(song) and override equals() method in Song class and try ?

Comment: have u debugged the code where it is going wrong, have you checked getName() ,songsList.get(i).getName()  both the method are they returning correct values to be compared?

Comment: Please show us the `Song` class. Besides, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. You pass a `Song` instance as an argument to the method, and you return a `Song` instance of the list that is equal to the argument? Why don't you just return the argument instead? Or maybe the argument could be just a `String` representing the name of the song? Please also show how you are invoking the method, the error must be surely there

Comment: Yes, add a driver where you build your song list and then call `findSong()` with one obvious match and one obvious mismatch.  The algorithm looks like it should work, so the problem is likely elsewhere in your code.

Comment: thx all, im checking the other pieces now, coming back with answer.

Comment: The error was pretty idiotic, i just neede to swap the positions of what the method will be returning, The return null inside the loop and the return song outside. i found the solution thx to the comments you guys wrote.thx.

Comment: @Noobest Now that you found the solution, why not post an answer to your own question?